# Attribute Error :'list' object has no function 'lower'

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, tf-idf, data-preprocessing, tfidfvectorizer

how to apply the lower function for preprocessing of text i am using this line
``df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].apply(lambda x: x.lower() if type(x)==str else x)`
but **tfidf** is giving  error ('list' object has no attribute 'lower')
[TFIDF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0aRG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple one try this, but it will convert all the values to str, regardless of its type.

```
`df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].str.lower()`
```

or if you want to do it with type check, using lambda it will be
`df['Sentences'] = df['Sentences'].apply(lambda x: str(x).lower() if type(x)==str else x)`